# Boost.Spirit parse string to number with radix

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a template function which casts string to number as following:

```
template <typename RetType,
    typename Parser =
    typename boost::spirit::traits::create_parser<RetType>::type>
    inline std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<RetType>::value, RetType>
    cast(const std::string &input)
{
    RetType result;

    if(input.empty())
    {
        // handle this
    }
    auto itBeg = input.cbegin();
    auto itEnd = input.cend();
    if(!bsq::parse(itBeg, itEnd, Parser(), result) || itBeg != itEnd)
    {
        // handle that
    }
    return result;
}
```

now I would like to create a function similar to above which will parse string that represents a number in some radix

```
template <typename RetType, unsigned Radix,
    typename Parser =
    typename boost::spirit::traits::create_parser<RetType>::type>
    inline std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<RetType>::value, RetType>
    cast(const std::string &input)
{
    RetType result;

    if(input.empty())
    {
        // handle this
    }
    auto itBeg = input.cbegin();
    auto itEnd = input.cend();
    if(!bsq::parse(itBeg, itEnd, Parser<RetType, Radix, 1 - 1>() /*something like this*/, result) || itBeg != itEnd)
    {
        // handle that
    }

    return result;
}
```

the Parser is invalid, of course, but what is the right way to define "automatic" arithmetic parser with radix?

Comment: yeah, I was aware of this possibility which I can achieve using type traits, but I guess there is something more elegant inside boost::spirit which can solve it more elegantly. We will wait for @hkaiser to show up :)

Comment: Oh. I won't answer then... :(

Comment: I just was sure you will show up :)

Comment: Gosh. The close-voting crowd really needs to lighten up. This question is interesting and well posed. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `qi::int_parser<>` directly:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bd4a2c9eb54e904)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename RetType, unsigned Radix = 10, typename Parser = typename boost::spirit::qi::int_parser<RetType, Radix> >
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<RetType>::value, RetType>::type
    cast(const std::string &input)
{
    RetType result;

    if(input.empty())
    {
        // handle this
    }
    auto itBeg = input.cbegin();
    auto itEnd = input.cend();
    if(!boost::spirit::qi::parse(itBeg, itEnd, Parser(), result) || itBeg != itEnd)
    {
        // handle that
        throw "oops";
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << cast<int>    ("10") << "\n";
    std::cout << cast<int,  2>("10") << "\n";
    std::cout << cast<int,  8>("10") << "\n";
    std::cout << cast<int, 16>("10") << "\n";
    std::cout << cast<int, 16>("ee") << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
10
2
8
16
238
```

> Hint: to be very accurate you might want to detect signed/unsigned types and use `uint_parser<>` accordingly

Comment: Much better than Heckler & Kaiser.

Comment: are you sure there is no better way to do that? this is the case which I would leave for the last resort. Also, didn't find any possibility of radix for real numbers (not that I need it right now) is it done by real_policy?

Comment: Why didn't you mention that in the question (along with your reasons for it)? There's no popular radix text representation for real numbers. It would not be hard to piece a real_policy together, I guess.

Comment: nah, it was just out of curiosity, when I dug in the spirit code I didnt see that functionality, and I was curious if it is just me missing it or it simply not there